# Uncaught TypeError: links is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html, error-handling

This is a **very strange** error. HTML thinks the function is undefined, how do I solve this? Here's the code:

```
<button id="links" onclick="links()">Links</button>
    <script>function links(){document.location = ("links.html")}</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that [`document.links`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/links)
 already exists, and implicit references to items on the global `document` willl take precedence over implicit references on the global `window`. That is, if `document.<something>` exists and `window.<something>` exists, if you just use `<something>` by itself, the interpreter will first check to see if the name you're using exists on `document` before checking to see if the name you're using exists in `window`. (Your `links` *function* exists at `window.links`)

> The `links` read-only property of the Document interface returns a collection of all  elements and  elements in a document with a value for the href attribute.

```html
<button id="links" onclick="console.log(links === document.links); links();">text content</button>
<script>
function links() {
  document.location = ("links.html")
}
</script>
```

Either refer to `window.links` instead of just `links`, which will default to `document.links`:

```html
<button id="links" onclick="window.links();">text content</button>
<script>
function links() {
  document.location = ("links.html")
}
</script>
```

Or, preferably, attach the handler properly using Javascript instead; inline handlers require pollution of the global scope and are generally considered to be pretty bad practice anyway:

```js
document.querySelector('#links').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.location = "links.html";
});
```

```html
<button id="links">text content</button>
```

Comment: oh, thanks, that works but button style in full page stil not displaying correctly

Comment: You didn't post any CSS in the question - sounds like an entirely separate issue.

Answer (score -2):

That's because you are invoking your function immediately. Try to change your code this way:

```
<button id="links" onclick="links">Links</button>
<script>function links(){document.location = ("links.html")}</script>
```